# Java: obtener objetos que son instancia de un tipo específico en un ArrayList sin recorrer todo el arreglo

Tags: java, arraylist, herencia

Mi duda esta en que si tengo un `ArrayList` de tipo de una clase padre como:

```
ArrayList<Objeto> objetos = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener los objetos de esa lista que son instancia de una clase hija especifica sin recorrer todo el arreglo?

Normalmente lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```
for (int i = 0; i < objetos.size(); i++) {
        if(objetos.get(i) instanceof Diamante){
            //....Codigo
        }
    }
```

Donde `Diamante` hereda de `Objeto`. Pero quisiera saber si se puede obtener solo los objetos `Diamante` de la lista como un `ArrayList` aparte o algo así.

Comment: Me temo que no se puede, tendrás siempre recorrer todos los elementos y filtrar los que coincidan con tu búsqueda. En general te puedo asegurar que posees un error en el diseño y/o arquitectura, después de todo no debe de haber distinción entre una clase padre y una clase hija...

Comment: Ok, Gracias por tu respuesta. :D

Comment: Con Java 8 puedes usar *streams*, pero lo único que hacen es simplificar el código que escribes, internamente recorren todo el array igual de forma que si el problema es el rendimiento no te ayudarán en nada.

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede hacer. Si lo que quieres es coger solo los objetos diamante te recomendaria que crearas otro ArrayList y guardaras todos los diamantes ahi. Yo lo haria de la siguiente manera :

```
public ArrayList<Objeto> devolverDiamantes(ArrayList<Objeto> objetos){
     ArrayList<Objeto> listaDiamantes = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
     for (int i = 0; i < objetos.size(); i++) {
         if(objetos.get(i) instanceof Diamante){
             listaDiamantes.add(objetos.get(i));
         }
     }
     return(listaDiamantes);
}
```

Comment: *¿Cómo puedo obtener los objetos de esa lista que son instancia de una clase hija especifica __sin recorrer todo el arreglo__?*

Comment: Eso no se puede hacer por lo menos si tienes los datos de esta manera. Es necesario que vayas mirando uno por uno como he mostrado en el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

No se puede hacer sin recorrer la Lista, no hay magia para encontrar elementos sin comprobar cada posición a menos que la lista esté ordenada y sepas en qué zona está lo que buscas (búsqueda binaria, por ejemplo).

Dicho esto, se puede abstraer el bucle haciendo lo siguiente:

```java
var diamantes = objetos.stream().filter(obj -> obj instanceof Diamante).toList();
```